# How to fix ArrayAdapter changing positions when listView scrolls?

Tags: java, android, listview, scrollview, android-arrayadapter

I still not used a ViewHolder class, (I know about the performance of the list view, and will implement it as soon as possible) but I already try overwrite those two methods on array adapter (`getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType`) but continue not working.

At my standpoint my array adapter onle handle with ONE type of view, so theoretically I didn't have to overwrite those methods, but i dont know what is happening, just when I scroll my listView the positions get disorganized.

My ArrayAdapter:

```
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Task> taskArrayList;

    public TasksAdapter(@NonNull Context c, @NonNull ArrayList<Task> objects) {
        super(c, R.layout.task_row, objects);
        this.context = c;
        this.taskArrayList = objects;

    }
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return taskArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        Task task = taskArrayList.get(position);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_row, parent, false);
        if(TaskActivity.getIsClicked() && TaskActivity.getPositionClicked()-1 == position){
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.backgroundSelectedItem);
        }      
        TextView timeTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
        TextView taskNameView = view.findViewById(R.id.taskNameText);
        TextView dateTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
        FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.myFabTask);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM");
        String dateString = sdf.format(task.getDate());
        int hour = (int) task.getTime()/3600000;
        int minutes = (int) (task.getTime() % 3600000) / 60000;
        String stringHour = Integer.toString(hour);
        String stringMinutes = Integer.toString(minutes);
        if(stringHour.length() == 1){stringHour = "0"+stringHour;}
        if(stringMinutes.length() == 1){stringMinutes = "0"+stringMinutes;}
        String timeString = stringHour+":"+stringMinutes;
        timeTextView.setText(timeString);
        taskNameView.setText(task.getName());
        dateTextView.setText(dateString);
        return view;
    }

My Main code where i call and use the adapter:




         mTaskListView = findViewById(R.id.task_list_view);
            refreshAdapter();
            isClicked = false;
            positionClicked = 0;
            mTaskListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if(positionClicked == (position+1) || positionClicked == 0){

                        if(!isClicked){
                            isClicked = true;
                            positionClicked = position+1;
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

                            changeLayoutVisibility(1);
                            Task task = adapter.getItem(position);
                           parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundSelectedItem));

                        }else {
                            isClicked = false;
                            positionClicked = 0;                      mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);                   
                            changeLayoutVisibility(0);
                        parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                        }
                    }
                }
            });


Function on Main activity:

    private void refreshAdapter() {
        adapter = null;
        //Get the array with tasks
        adapter = new TasksAdapter(this, mDBAdapter.getAllTask());
        //Set the list view
        mTaskListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

My row of listView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="@color/controlColorNormal"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/taskNameText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timeTextView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/timeTextView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/timeTextView"
    android:text="Nome da tarefa"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/taskNameText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/taskNameText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/taskNameText"
    android:text="Data adicionada"
    android:textColor="@color/colorHint" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/myFabTask"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_send"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    app:fabSize="mini">

</android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>
```

My List View:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/task_list_view"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="475dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="true"
    android:divider="@color/borderColor"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:theme="@style/MyPicker"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: why don't you can use recyclerview instead of listview?

Comment: Why should i use? I didn't know about recycleview

Comment: Refer the link
https://android.jlelse.eu/recyclerview-listview-basic-comparison-91e844a2fbc4

Answer (score 0):

> Don't do following operations in getView().

```
//get and format the date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM");
String dateString = sdf.format(task.getDate());

//convert the milliseconds to minute and hour
int hour = (int) task.getTime()/3600000;
int minutes = (int) (task.getTime() % 3600000) / 60000;
String stringHour = Integer.toString(hour);
String stringMinutes = Integer.toString(minutes);
if(stringHour.length() == 1){stringHour = "0"+stringHour;}
if(stringMinutes.length() == 1){stringMinutes = "0"+stringMinutes;}

String timeString = stringHour+":"+stringMinutes;
```

Create new Function which return type is **String** and call that function in `timeTextView.setText`.

- Make function Like this:

  ```
  private String getTimeStirng(Object date){
      //get and format the date
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM");
      String dateString = sdf.format(date);

      //convert the milliseconds to minute and hour
      int hour = (int) task.getTime()/3600000;
      int minutes = (int) (date % 3600000) / 60000;
      String stringHour = Integer.toString(hour);
      String stringMinutes = Integer.toString(minutes);
      if(stringHour.length() == 1){stringHour = "0"+stringHour;}
      if(stringMinutes.length() == 1){stringMinutes = "0"+stringMinutes;}

      String timeString = stringHour+":"+stringMinutes;

      return timeString;
  }
  ```
- Call it like: `timeTextView.setText(getTimeString(task.getDate()));`

Thanks.
Happy Coding.

Comment: I'm using this method all time, it is working. Check carefully where you are mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You said that your adapter only handle with ONE type of view but:

1. When `@Override  getViewTypeCount()` you return the size of `taskArrayList`, so the system understand that you have `taskArrayList.size()` type of view.  In your case, it should be 1.
2. List item In `getItemViewType()` method, the value return must is the identify of view type, not the item's position. In your case also, it should return 0 as default.

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

I just solve it by changing:

```
parent.
    getChildAt(position).
    setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundSelectedItem));
```

By:

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.backgroundSelectedItem);
```